# Free XML Formatting tool

Tags: xml, xml-formatting

Is there a free XML formatting (indent) tool available where I can past an XML string and have it formatted so I can read the XML document correctly?

Thanks

Edit ~ I am using XML Notepad on Windows XP.

Comment: What platform are you on? What text editor are you already using? Most decent text editors either support this out of the box or have add-ons available.

Comment: I found this very constructive

Comment: Agree.  This question actually is a good fit to the Q&A: there was a factual answer to a narrow question.  This question shouldn't have been closed.

Comment: I also agree. The answers to this question provide useful information. Also, closing a question 2 years after it was asked seems rather silly.

Comment: The Best Formatter --> http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html

Comment: Sublime Text + Indent XML

Comment: This one is very handy to use: http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/xml-formatter.html

Comment: I like this one, https://xmlexplorer.codeplex.com/, not really an editor, but rather a browser, displays tree hierarchiy, accepts XPath queries, and very low footprint (I used with files of 30 MBs). Good for getting the big picture (of the document structure).

Comment: Another one, more like traditional editor: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmltreeeditor/

Comment: 1. CodVerter XML Validator - https://codverter.com/src/xmlvalidator  2. CodVerter XML to Plain Text - https://codverter.com/src/xmltotext CodVerter 3. XML to JSON - https://codverter.com/src/xmltojson

Answer (score 352, accepted):

I believe that [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/) has this feature.

**Edit (for newer versions)**
Install the "XML Tools" plugin (Menu Plugins, Plugin Manager)
Then run: Menu Plugins, Xml Tools, Pretty Print (XML only - with line breaks)

**Original answer (for older versions of Notepad++)**

Notepad++ menu: TextFX -> HTML Tidy -> Tidy: Reindent XML

This feature however wraps XMLs and that makes it look 'unclean'.
To have no wrap,

- open `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\Config\tidy\TIDYCFG.INI`,
- find the entry `[Tidy: Reindent XML]` and add `wrap:0` so that it looks like this:

```
[Tidy: Reindent XML] 
input-xml: yes 
indent:yes 
wrap:0
```

Comment: You might need http://www.twu.ca/divisions/technology/sst/orion/blog/tidy-notepad-and-xml.html

Comment: I verified this works without plug-ins.  Just download the latest version of Notepad++ and it will support this.

Comment: +1 Was looking for this the other day in Notepad++

Comment: Who would have ever thought you'd get this many up votes for pointing out a feature in Notepad++?  But once I used it, I up voted it too.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It's funny (misleading?) that HTMLTidy is described as a feature of Notepad++.  It is a standalone tool (http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) that has been around much longer than Notepad++ and can be used in any text editor that supports external tools. I used it for ages from the command prompt before I found FirstObject XML Editor.

Comment: Notepad++ 's XML indent feature however wraps XMLs and that makes it look 'unclean'. I like the way IE represents it. To have no wrap for "Tidy: Reindent XML", open "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\Config\tidy\TIDYCFG.INI", find the entry "[Tidy: Reindent XML]" and add "wrap:0" so that it looks like this:

[Tidy: Reindent XML]
input-xml: yes
indent:yes
wrap:0

This should give non-wrapped XML

Comment: Notepad++ seems to need to run as administrator (in Windows 7) to be able to Reindent XML, even at a 'random' location. It took me quite a while before I figured that one out. [I guess this is more like a comment, but I don't have enoug Rep for that.]

Comment: I prefer Notepad++ because I can optionally copy the highlighting into emails using Plugins -> NppExport -> Copy all formats to clipboard

Comment: I think this tip about the wrapping should be in the answer itself. Will attempt to edit the answer to add it.

Comment: @Guy Is there any way to say not to escape xml? Because by default it is escaping it.

Comment: Just FYI, the newest version of Notepad++ (5.9 at the time of writing) does not include TextFX, and getting it to work requires manual building of a DLL.  In the Plugin Manager, install the XML Tools plugin -- MUCH easier.

Comment: Very nice, MUCH faster than Eclipse.

Comment: One thing to be aware of, if you use Pretty Print (XML only - with line breaks) and then modify the file and save it, a CR/LF will be written to the file at the end of each line. By using Pretty Print (XML only - with line breaks) you are not just changing the view of the file, you are changing the file contents as well. Use View / Show Symbol / Show all characters to see the added control chars in the file.

Comment: @Tary But that's what you need when you select *'...with line breaks'*, right? `CRLF`s and `Tab`s. That changes the file, but not the 'document'.

Comment: I installed Notepad++ v7.5.8 (64-bit) and installed any XML plugin I could find. Nothing worked.

Comment: @Peter you have to install the 32 bit version of notepad++. The Plugin Admin option is not available under the Plugins menu in the 64 bit version.

Answer (score 61):

[Firstobject's free XML editor for Windows is called foxe](http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm) is a great tool.

Open or paste your XML into it and press F8 to indent (you may need to set the number of indent spaces as it may default to 0).

It looks simple, however it contains a custom written XML parser written in C++ that allows it to work efficiently with **very large XML files** easily (unlike some expensive "espionage" related tools I've used).

*From the product page:*

> The full Visual C++ source code for this firstobject XML editor
>   (including the CDataEdit gigabyte edit control MFC component) is
>   available as part of the Advanced CMarkup Developer License. It allows
>   developers to implement custom XML handling functions such as
>   validation, transformation, beautify, and reporting for their own
>   purposes.

Comment: Ha, expensive "espionage"...one for the day :)

Comment: That's a neat tool. Tiny as well.

Comment: It even renders entities, that's really handy!

Comment: Thanks, incredibly fast!  Loaded up a ~15MB file in a few seconds!

Comment: this is so much better than that xml tool plugin in notepad++

Comment: I have a 15MB file - Notepad++ was thrashing 1 core for many minutes without a result, Visual Studio was doing the same (and slowing chewing more and more memory. Foxe can open and format it instantly - impressive.  UI is plan-jane but it does the job.

Comment: @MikeHoney: same for me. I love Notepad++ but it was crashing on big files. I have a 45MB file, threw it at Foxe, result: instantly opened! 8|

Comment: Yes I've since used it on files over 300MB with no dramas.

Comment: I was trying to indent a 85MB xml file. This worked almost instantly. Amazing.

Answer (score 55):

Use the following:

> [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) `--format`

Comment: my cygwin distro already had this so I guess I didn't need to download the windows binary and then decide I'd rather write a bash script

Answer (score 22):

You can open the XML file in any Visual Studio Express product and the press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to get it nicely formatted.

Hey, it's free and it's a tool, so it fits the question. :-)

Comment: I used to do this :D Well, I had a proper VS edition. I'm so glad I know of better lightweight tools now!

Comment: All this time, I've been copying it from VS to Notepad++ just to format the xml, and I could have just done that! What's more, I use Ctrl+K Ctrl+F to format code already. :-) Nice one.

Comment: And can even be simplified a little since Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D formats the whole document so you can skip the Ctrl+A.

Answer (score 17):

Another method to reindent XML in Notepad++:

From menu select Plugins -> XML Tools -> Pretty print (XML only – with line breaks)
or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

Comment: you might need to add the plugin before you can do this. add via the Plugin Manager

Comment: even with this plugin, NPP gets quite slower even opening 20+ MB files on my Core-i5/8GB pc

Answer (score 5):

You could also try http://xmltoolbox.appspot.com/ it is an online xml formatter. You just paste your xml into a large text area field and press "format xml" then it pretty prints the xml in the text area so its easy to read or copy.

There is also a nice little filter feature that allows you to see all of a certain element.

Hope you will enjoy the tool

Answer (score 4):

If you use Notepad++, I would suggest installing the [XML Tools](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=189927&package_id=264094) plugin. You can beautify any XML content (indentation and line breaks) or linarize it. Also you can (auto-)validate your file and apply XSL transformation to it.

Download the latest zip and copy the extracted DLL to the plugins directory of your Notepad++ installation. Also, download the External libs and copy them to your %SystemRoot%\system32\ directory.

Comment: Actually you will need the ext_libs as well, there is an exe that will do the whole thing for you in the source forge repo

Answer (score 3):

**Advanced Conventional Formatting** [Update]

[XMLSpectrum](https://github.com/pgfearo/xmlspectrum) is an open source syntax-highlighter. Supporting XML - but with special features for XSLT 2.0, XSD 1.1 and XPath 2.0. I'm mentioning this here because it also has special formatting capabilities for XML: it vertically aligns attributes and their contents as well as elements - to enhance XML readability.

The output HTML is suitable for reviewing in a browser or if the XML needs further editing it can be copied and pasted into an XML editor of your choice

Because *xmlspectrum.xsl* uses its own XML text parser, all content such as entity references and CDATA sections are preserved - as in an editor.

[image]

*Note on usage: this is just an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet so you would need to enclose the required command-line (samples provided) in a small script so you could automatically transform the XML source.*

**Virtual Formatting**

[XMLQuire](http://qutoric.com/xmlquire) is a free XML editor that has special formatting capabilities - it formats XML properly, including multi-line attributes, attribute-values, word-wrap indentation and even XML comments.

All XML indentation is done without inserting tabs or spaces, ensuring the integrity of the XML is maintained. For versions of Windows later than XP, no installation is needed, its just a 3MB .exe file.

If you need to print out the formatted XML there are special options within the print-preview,  such as line-numbering that follows the indentation. If you need to copy the formatted XML to a word processor as rich text, that's available too.

[Disclosure: I maintain both XMLQuire and XMLSpectrum as 'home projects']

Comment: I just blogged about this here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2013/01/09/how-to-format-xaml-easily-and-effectively-windows-8-wpf-silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not directly an answer, but good to know nevertheless: After indenting, please make sure that the parser(s) and application(s) which will subsequently process the formatted XML will not yield different results. [White space is often significant in XML](http://xml.silmaril.ie/whitespace.html) and most conforming parsers bubble it up to the application.

Comment: A notorious example of semantically significant whitespace occurs in **WPF**. Specifically, adjacent `<Run />` tags will [introduce a (usually unwanted) space in the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090084/how-to-get-rid-of-whitespace-between-runs-in-textblock), unless those tags are strictly abutting in the **XAML** source file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a programmer, many XML parsing programming libraries will let you parse XML, then output it - and generating pretty printed, indented output **is** an output option.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ dit it well only if you're in ANSI.
If you do it in something like "ANSI AS UTF8", tidy dirty the doc :/.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://prettydiff.com/  The algorithm is similar to HTML Tidy, but is more complete.  The program is written entirely in JavaScript, so you don't have to install anything.