# How to get rid of whitespace between Runs in TextBlock?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have following XAML:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                               FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="#414141">        
                                            <Run Text="{Binding LoadsCount}" />        
                                            <Run Text="+" />        
                                            <Run Text="{Binding BrokerLoadsCount}" />
                                        </TextBlock>
```

And I get display like this: `12 + 11` 
Somehow it inserts extra space between each `Run`
How do I make it display `12+11` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextBlock with multiple <Run> spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130285/textblock-with-multiple-run-spacing)

Comment: @katit No, it was asked an year after.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The spaces between the run tags cause the spaces, this is the easiest fix.

```
<TextBlock 
   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
   VerticalAlignment="Center"
   FontSize="10" 
   FontFamily="Arial" 
   Foreground="#414141">        
      <Run Text="{Binding LoadsCount}" /><Run Text="+" /><Run Text="{Binding BrokerLoadsCount}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Because anything between the `<TextBlock>` and `</TextBlock>` is targeting the text property of the TextBlock the whitespace from the breaks between the runs causes the effect you see.  You could also shorten it to this.

```
<Run Text="{Binding LoadsCount}" />+<Run Text="{Binding BrokerLoadsCount}" />
```

This MSDN article gives all the specifics on how xaml handles the whitespace

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788746.aspx

If you were curious why a break and a ton of tabs translates into a single space

> All whitespace characters (space, linefeed, tab) are converted into
>   spaces.
>
> All consecutive spaces are deleted and replaced by one space

Comment: The problem with this solution is as soon as you apply a formatter (like XAML Styler) everything's back to the original problem. So in a big XAML file with hundreds of lines you gotta make sure to go back and remove all those line breaks after each format.

Answer (score 50):

Another option is to comment the space between Run tags, maintaining the code readable and removing the extra space.

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="#414141">        
    <Run Text="{Binding LoadsCount}" /><!--
 --><Run Text="+" /><!--
 --><Run Text="{Binding BrokerLoadsCount}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 24):

One problem with Kevin's nice solution is that the single-line formatting of `XAML` tags is undone when you apply some of the XAML/XML automatic reformatting functions, e.g. "ctrl-K + ctrl-D". One workaround I found is to format the `Run` tags as follows:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run FontStyle="Italic"
    Text="aaa" /><Run 
    Text="bbb" />
</TextBlock>
```

Although splitting the tag across lines like this is somewhat awkward, this format will not be altered by automatic reformatting, provided you select the `Visual Studio` option "Preserve new lines and spaces between attributes" for the XAML text editor:

[image: extra space eliminated between consecutive Run elements in XAML]

Answer (score 2):

I've written a Attached Property to 'bypass' this behavior.

```
public class TextBlockExtension
{

    public static bool GetRemoveEmptyRuns(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(RemoveEmptyRunsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetRemoveEmptyRuns(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(RemoveEmptyRunsProperty, value);

        if (value)
        {
            var tb = obj as TextBlock;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.Loaded += Tb_Loaded;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RemoveEmptyRunsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RemoveEmptyRuns", typeof(bool), 
            typeof(TextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public static bool GetPreserveSpace(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(PreserveSpaceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPreserveSpace(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(PreserveSpaceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PreserveSpaceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PreserveSpace", typeof(bool), 
            typeof(Run), new PropertyMetadata(false));


    private static void Tb_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = sender as TextBlock;
        tb.Loaded -= Tb_Loaded;

       var spaces = tb.Inlines.Where(a => a is Run 
            && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((Run)a).Text) 
            && !GetPreserveSpace(a)).ToList();
        spaces.ForEach(s => tb.Inlines.Remove(s));
    }
}
```

The entire source code and the explanation of it all can be found [here](http://blog.pieeatingninjas.be/2016/11/19/getting-rid-of-whitespaces-between-runs-in-a-textblock/). 
By using this attached property you can keep your XAML formatting just the way you want, but you don't get these whitespaces in your rendered XAML.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to make the default font size nearly invisible(`FontSize="1"`) and then set the font size to the desired size at every each `<Run`:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="1"
           FontFamily="Arial"
           Foreground="#414141">        

    <Run FontSize="10" Text="{Binding LoadsCount}" />        
    <Run FontSize="10" Text="+" />        
    <Run FontSize="10" Text="{Binding BrokerLoadsCount}" />
</TextBlock>
```

You may be better off doing it in Code Behind. I have tried previous solutions but in certain situations VS just formatted away the carefully indented code.

Answer (score 2):

I ported Pieter's attached property to WPF (I think it's for UWP).

Example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Before:" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
    <TextBlock>
        Foo
        <Run Text="Bar"/>
        <Run>Baz</Run>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="After:" FontWeight="SemiBold" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
    <TextBlock local:TextBlockHelper.TrimRuns="True">
        Foo
        <Run Text="Bar"/>
        <Run>Baz</Run>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="Use two spaces if you want one:" FontWeight="SemiBold" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
    <TextBlock local:TextBlockHelper.TrimRuns="True">
        Foo
        <Run Text="  Bar"/>
        <Run>Baz</Run>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: screenshot]

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

public class TextBlockHelper
{
    public static bool GetTrimRuns(TextBlock textBlock) => (bool)textBlock.GetValue(TrimRunsProperty);
    public static void SetTrimRuns(TextBlock textBlock, bool value) => textBlock.SetValue(TrimRunsProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TrimRunsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TrimRuns", typeof(bool), typeof(TextBlockHelper),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, OnTrimRunsChanged));

    private static void OnTrimRunsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBlock = d as TextBlock;
        textBlock.Loaded += OnTextBlockLoaded;
    }

    static void OnTextBlockLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
        textBlock.Loaded -= OnTextBlockLoaded;

        var runs = textBlock.Inlines.OfType<Run>().ToList();
        foreach (var run in runs)
            run.Text = TrimOne(run.Text);
    }

    private static string TrimOne(string text)
    {
        if (text.FirstOrDefault() == ' ')
            text = text.Substring(1);
        if (text.LastOrDefault() == ' ')
            text = text.Substring(0, text.Length - 1);

        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: One more update to Your solution. Get rid of `TrimOne` method and use this foreach inside `OnTextBlockLoaded`: `foreach (var run in runs.Where(run => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(run.Text)))
                run.Text = string.Empty;`

It will just flush whitespace runs and will not remove Your own spaces. :)

Comment: @Genotypek, that doesn't seem to remove the unwanted space after "Foo". It should work if all text is in `<Run>`s.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that looks cleaner is to use `<TextBlock.Inlines>` tag inside the `<TextBlock>`:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="#414141">
            <TextBlock.Inlines>
                <Run Text="{Binding LoadsCount}" />        
                <Run Text="+" />        
                <Run Text="{Binding BrokerLoadsCount}" />
            </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: This seems not to remove any whitespace between runs