# ControlTemplate TextBlock Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates

When I have TextBlock. Run Text = "(" Run Text={Binding IncomeLoss} Run Text=")" in a Page it comes out looking ok,
but when I have the same thing inside a ControlTemplate that I apply to a class that derives from Control, there is extra space after each character like "( 100 ) ".

I read that ControlTemplate is a barrier to style inheritance, but how do I guess what exactly style parameter is the one missing that is usually inherited by the Textblock on a Page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have put all `Run` elements on the same line in the `ControlTemplate`.

There is a difference in output between this:

```
<TextBlock><Run Text = "(" /><Run Text="{Binding IncomeLoss}"/><Run Text=")"/></TextBlock>
```

...and this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text = "(" />
    <Run Text="{Binding IncomeLoss}"/>
    <Run Text=")"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: That's it.  If you could elaborate, briefly, on a why this is exactly, and ... a good way to keep my markup organized without a 120 column 600 DPI display and 8-power reading glasses.

Comment: Whitespace characters (space, linefeed, tab) are converted into spaces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090084/how-to-get-rid-of-whitespace-between-runs-in-textblock