# How to bring two TextBlock 'Runs' together

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, textblock

I used this code to make one `TextBlock` with 2 different fonts:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" FontSize="48" RelativePanel.Below="textBlock2" Margin="0,20,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe UI" IsTextSelectionEnabled="True">
    <Run x:Name="textBlock3_1">00:00:00</Run>
    <Run x:Name="textBlock3_2" FontSize="20">.00</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

But it makes the two texts a bit too far apart from each other:

[image]

Is there a way to make them come closer? I tried setting the margins, turns out they didn't have a margin property.

EDIT: I also want to figure out how to make `textBlock3_2` aligned to the top. I couldn't find this property as well.

Comment: I dont know anything about UWP, but maybe you can provide a negative margin on one of the runs?

Comment: Did you check out the following answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090084/how-to-get-rid-of-whitespace-between-runs-in-textblock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I succeeded to correct it by leaving the two run items on the same line (without spaces between them)

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" FontSize="48"  Margin="0,20,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe UI" >
        <Run x:Name="textBlock3_1">00:00:00</Run><Run x:Name="textBlock3_2" FontSize="20" BaselineAlignment="TextTop">.00</Run>
    </TextBlock>
```

Edit: I added an extra property for your additional request